# Users access on Resources, Resource Group, Subscription in Azure How to get through the Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, access-control-list, rbac

I have Subscription where lots of Resources and Resource group created, i want to list all user access and what type for access level user has like Owner contributor rider through the Powershell

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Use the Az PowerShell module
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell#list-access

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: What error do you get?